# HTTPWebRequest - to "visit" a page - C#

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest

Ok I've been reading qutie a lot of pages to try and find the answer to my problem but I'm not having any luck. Basically I want to use a HTTPWebRequest in C# to visit a webpage. This is what I have so far and it doesn't seem to be working. Wireshark doesn't show any returned cookies either. Assume I have declared everything I need to please:

```
private void cmdVisit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        url = textBox1.Text;

        string front = "http://";
        string prx = front + lstProxy.Items[x].ToString();

        WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy(prx);
        CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

       request.Method = "GET";
       request.Proxy = myProxy;
       request.Referer = "http://anyrefererItypehere";
       request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
       request.ContentType = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
       request.KeepAlive = true;
       request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate");
       request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2";
       request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5");
       request.Host = "anyblogItypehere.tumblr.com";

      HttpWebResponse webResponse;
      webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

        webResponse.Close();
        rtbSource.Text = responseString;


        }
```

Comment: you mean `responseString` is empty?

Comment: Can you post an example url ?

Comment: The URL could be anything. Assume it's a blog on Tumblr. I can pick one at random if you wish? Also, response string is empty since I added everything from cookiecontainer down. That's not the issue though, the problem is that the above code doesn't emulate a site visit.

Comment: Ok, but your problem is that you did not receive any response from url, or what? Can you try to access page without proxy

Comment: Accessing the page seems to be fine and I can return a page string. But the issue I am having is that it doesn't seem to be registering my get request as a site visit. I think it is something to do with cookies. Should the above code be ok to capture all cookies?

Comment: @ThomasPollock where do you see site visits?  It's possible they're being recorded via javascript or tracking pixels (ie, google analytics).

Comment: Yes it's google analytics I'm using to "track" these visits.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get the content from a web page (error handling code omitted for clarity):

```
 public static string GetContent(string uri)
 {
     using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
     {
         // Pretend to be IE6
         client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
         return client.DownloadString(uri);
      }
  }
```

If you want to specify a proxy, use the Proxy property on the client object.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I use wireshark to visit the webpage through a browser there are alot more headers specified plus cookies. So wouldn't I need to add all those for it to emulate a proper visit?

Comment: You can add the extra headers you see in the wireshark capture, and the cookies too if required. A real browser would then also download any linked resources, and run any scripts and plugin specific code in the supplied content, deal with authentication requests, act on response headers (redirects etc), and so on. It all depends what you are trying to achieve with your code.

Comment: A full simulation is much more complicated. For example, the request patterns from users will all be different depending on their browser, its configuration, what plugins it has installed, how long they spend on each page, current network conditions, whether they are authenticated with the site, etc etc.